# Реализация абстрактной коллекции

Tags: php, ооп, коллекции

Помогите пожалуйста реализовать абстрактный класс коллекции.

Хочется написать свой велосипед, чтобы до конца понять, как это должно работать и т.д.

Этот класс должен решить проблемы c типизацией возвращаемых значений метода.

Как я себе это представляю:

```
class PostCollection extends BaseCollection {

    # Устанавливаю тип коллекции, 
    # при попытке добавить в коллекцию другой тип - выбрасываем исключение

    protected static $collectionType = PostItem::class;

}

class PostItem {
   //...
}

class Posts {
   public function getAllPost() : PostCollection { ... }
}
```

Также, желательно, чтобы у абстрактного класса таже были реализованы интерфейсы `Iterator`, `ArrayAccess`, `Countable`;

Также планирую добавлять такие методы как `map()`, `sort()` и т.д.

Готовой реализации не требую. От вас нужна помощь, чтобы подсказали, как правильно нужно реализовать такие коллекции, какие нюансы стоит учесть?
Правильно ли я через статическое свойство `$collectionType` определяю тип текущей коллекции ?

Или есть какие-то другие варианты ?

Пробовал разобрать, как устроены коллекции в laravel или других фреймворках.
Было сложно и непонятно. Очень много кода, предусмотрено все, и на все случаи жизни. Еще и через рефлексию и т.д. 
Мне хотелось бы минимально рабочую версию реализовать.

За помощь буду очень благодарен!

Comment: Никто не знает?(

Comment: Все .овнокодят :))

Comment: Я постараюсь объяснить, но для этого нужно время, вопрос того требует)

Comment: @Mully хорошо, спасибо большое!

Comment: @Mully поможете?)

Answer (score 0):

В "минимальной рабочей версии" это должно выглядеть как то так:

```
abstract class BaseCollection
{
    private   $items = [];
    protected $collectionType;

    public function get(): array
    {
        return $this->items;
    }

    public function first()
    {
        return array_shift($this->items);
    }

    public function add($item): void
    {
        $this->checkItemType($item);

        $this->items[] = $item;
    }

    private function checkItemType($item)
    {
        if (get_class($item) !== $this->collectionType) {
            throw new Exception('bad type item');
        }

    }
}


class PostCollection extends BaseCollection
{
    protected $collectionType = PostItem::class;

}

class PostItem
{
    private $name;

    public function __construct(string $name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

class Posts
{
    public function getAllPost(): PostCollection
    {
        $collection = new PostCollection();

        $collection->add(new PostItem('first'));
        $collection->add(new PostItem('last'));

        return $collection;
    }
}


$posts = new Posts();
$collection = $posts->getAllPost();

echo $collection->first()->getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

я бы в отличии от @Romka пошел другим путем

делаете не класс, а трейт, типа

```php
trait CollectionBehavior
{
    protected $values = [];

    public function __construct(...$values)
    {
        foreach ($values as $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                if (!empty($value))
                    array_map([$this, 'add'], $value);
            } else {
                $this->add($value);
            }
        }
    }

    /** @return static */
    public static function of($values)
    {
        return new static($values);
    }

    /** @return static */
    public static function empty()
    {
        return new static([]);
    }

    public function isEmpty(): bool
    {
        return empty($this->values);
    }

    public function isNotEmpty(): bool
    {
        return !$this->isEmpty();
    }

    public function count(): int
    {
        return count($this->values);
    }

    public function map(callable $callable): array
    {
        return array_map($callable, $this->values);
    }

    public function reduce(callable $callable, $start = null)
    {
        return array_reduce($this->values, $callable, $start);
    }

    /**
     * @param callable $callable
     * @param int $mode
     * @return static
     */
    public function filter(callable $callable, $mode = 0)
    {
        return new self(array_filter($this->values, $callable, $mode));
    }

    public function getAll(): array
    {
        return $this->values;
    }

    public function merge(self $collection): self
    {
        $values = array_merge($this->values, $collection->values);
        return self::of($values);
    }
}
```

и, пользовательский код выглядел бы как:

```php
$item = new MyItem();
$item2 = new MyItem();
$item3 = new MyItem();
$item4 = new MyItem();
$myItemCollectionExample1 = new MyItemFactory($item,$item2,$item3,$item4);
$myItemCollectionExample2 = new MyItemFactory([$item,$item2,$item3,$item4]);
```

а код класса соответственно

```php
class MyItemCollection
{
    use CollectionBehavior;

    private function add(MyItem $item): void
    {
        // тут полностью на ваше усмотрение
        $this->items[$item->getId()] = $item;
    }
}
```

P.S изначально на проекте мы просто в коллекциях дописывали нужные нам методы, затем наш тимлид просто собрал все базовые случаи в код выше, и теперь пользуемся этим